# for_each & ranged base for on 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I was trying to print a 2D array using `for_each` and range based `for` loop.

My program goes like this:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
  //for_each (begin(a), end(a), [] (int x) { cout<<x<<" ";}); this code throws error

  for_each (begin(a[0]), end(a[2]), [] (int x) { cout<<x<<" ";});  //this code works well, why ?

  cout<<endl;

  for  (auto &row: a)  // without & for row, error is thrown
  {
     for (auto x:row)  // no & needed for x, why ?
     {
        cout<<x<<" ";
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why did my first `for_each` throw errors and why is `&` symbol necessary for row? What is its type? Is `row` a pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for_each (begin(a), end(a), [] (int x) { cout<<x<<" ";});
```

`begin(a)` yields an `int(*)[3]` (pointer to array of size [3]), and dereferencing it yields an `int(&)[3]`, while your lambda expression expects an `int` argument.

```
for_each (begin(a[0]), end(a[2]), [] (int x) { cout<<x<<" ";});
```

`begin(a[0])` yields an `int*` that points to the first element in the first row of `a`, and `end(a[2])` yields an `int*` pointing to one past the last element in the last row of `a`, so everything works.

---

Now for the range-based `for` part.

If you remove the `&` from the line `for (auto& row : a)` the error actually occurs on the following line `for(auto x : row)`. This is because of the way the [range-based `for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is specified. The clause pertinent to your use case is

> If `__range` is an array, then *begin_expr* is `__range` and *end_expr* is `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed)

Hereon I'll be referring to the identifiers mentioned in the **Explanation** section of the linked page.

---

Consider the case `for (auto& row : a)`:

`__range` is deduced as `int(&)[3][3]` (reference to array of size [3][3]). `__begin` is then deduced as `int(*)[3]` (pointer to array of size [3]) because the type of `__range` decays to a pointer to the first row of the 2D array. The *range_expression* you have is `auto& row`, so `row` is deduced as `int(&)[3]` (reference to array of size [3]).

Next, the same process is repeated for the inner range-based `for`. In this case, `__range` is `int(&)[3]` and the array clause I quoted above applies; the remaining type deduction process is similar to what I described above.

```
__range = int(&)[3]
__begin = int*
x       = int
```

---

Now consider the case `for (auto row : a)`:

`__range`, `__begin` and `__end` are all deduced the same. The crucial difference in this case is the *range_expression* `auto row`, which causes decay of the `int(*)[3]` type that `__begin` was deduced as. This means `row` is deduced as `int *`, and none of the 3 clauses where the determination of *begin_expr*/*end_expr* are described handle a raw pointer. This results in a compilation error within the nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a two-dimensional array - an `int[][]` if you like.

This means that when you iterate `a`, you are iterating only the first array dimension - `a[0]` through to `a[2]`. `a[0]` is still an array, which explains why your first `for_each` might produce an error - the lambda you provided is expecting an `int` but would be passed an `int*`.

The reference (& symbol) is needed in the first range-based for for the same reason. Without the & the compiler attempts to copy-by-value the items in the first dimension, but these are arrays themselves, and you can't copy an array by value in C++.

The second range-based for doesn't need a reference because it is iterating the second array dimension, which consists of simple ints.